# Was any verse in bori Mahabharata in which Shiva said that he was born from Vishnu or Vishnu said that Shiva born from Vishnu

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, shiva, vishnu, philosophy

Was there is any verse in bori Mahabharata in which Shiva said that he was born from Vishnu or Vishnu said that Shiva was born from him

Comment: it’s said here but not sure if this is in BORI: https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c041.htm